# Converting XML metadata to WMS?

Tags: data, wms, import, xml, metadata

I am currently creating an online GeoPortal for open data with the idea being that a user sources open data from a source such as the following: http://www.opendataphilly.org/opendata/resource/60/aerial-photography-2008/

The user then logs into the portal and using one of the menus can import this data as XML metadata using this example and the portal take this file and convert it into WMS ready to then display to the user.

Is this possible? And if so how would I go about achieving this?